# Populate field from json in c#

Tags: c#, json, .net, api

just started to playing with C#, and I want to populate field from json (want to show each event)

Here is my json information which I am using:

```
[
    
    {
        "event": {
            "date": "December 2, 2022, 20:00 pm",
            "id": "12345",
            "day": "December 2",
            "hour": "20:00 pm",
            "year": "2022",
            "event": "wedding", 
        },
        "test": [
            {
                "test1": {
                    "avg": 100,
                    "max": 160
                },
                "test2": {
                    "avg": 130,
                    "max": 150
                },
                "test3": {
                    "avg": 180,
                    "max": 200
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "event": {
            "date": "December 3, 2022, 20:00 pm",
            "id": "34567",
            "day": "December 3",
            "hour": "20:00 pm",
            "year": "2022",
            "event": "birthday",
        },
        "test": [
            {
                "test1": {
                    "avg": 200,
                    "max": 250
                },
                "test2": {
                    "avg": 50,
                    "max": 60
                },
                "test3": {
                    "avg": 70,
                    "max": 80
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Lets say I want to show test for each events in Console, I created a code like:

```
public class Test
    {
        public double avg { get; set; }
        public double max { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test2
    {
        public double avg { get; set; }
        public double max { get; set; }
    }
    public class Test3
    {
        public double avg { get; set; }
        public double max { get; set; }
    }
    public class Test
    {
        public Test1 test1 { get; set; }
        public Test2 test2 { get; set; }
        public Test3 test3 { get; set; }
    }


    public class Root
    {
        
        public Event event { get; set; }
        public List<Test> tests { get; set; }
    }


private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

        string link = "myurl";
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(link);
        request.ContentType= "application/json";
        var Token = "mytoken";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        using (Stream datastream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(datastream);
            string responsefromserver = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(responsefromserver);

            //here I want to show test for each event          
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

So, how can I show event in Console?
I got error when run the code:
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Program+Root' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.

If you could give me some hints it would be great

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your JSON information is missing.

Comment: @Ivana: It's still not clear to me what you're asking.  What code have you written and in what way is it not working as expected?  If you're just asking how to deserialize JSON data in C#, your favorite search engine can help you find many examples.

Comment: @MarvinKlein, here is

Comment: Try `Deserialize<Event[]>`. What you're trying to deserialize now would require an object with an `event` property that contains the array, but there's no such object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be a mismatch between your JSON and your object structure.  The root of your JSON is not an *object* with an `event` *property*.  It is an *array* of objects, *each of which* has an `event` property.

Update your `Root` class to correct the property:

```
public class Root
{
    public Event event { get; set; }
}
```

And update your deserialization to match the array in the JSON data:

```
Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(responsefromserver);
```

Then you can loop over your objects and output whatever data you like:

```
foreach (var obj in root)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Event: {obj.event.event}");
}
```

Comment: @Ivana: Please don't vandalize a question by replacing it with a new question.  If the question has been answered and you've moved on to another problem in your code, please create a new question to specifically describe that problem.  Otherwise what we'd have here is a "moving target" that can never be answered because the question keeps changing.